# Element.findElement() not working for native iOS App with any locator strategy using Appium

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to **find an element inside a webelement/mobileelement** and it's not working from automation code as well as from Appium Inspector

**Setup:**

- Appium 1.4.8
- XCode 6.3.2
- iOS Simulator: iPhone with iOS 8.3
- App: Native iOS App

**Locating strategies tried:** Xpath, name, class, ios uiautomation

Element hierarchy is as in the image:
[image: App element hierarchy]

My automation code is as below:

```
 WebElement itemElement = driver.findElements(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells().withPredicate(\"name == 'id_itemSummaryView'\")").get(0);//This will return a single element out of 4 elements
 itemElement.findElement(MobileBy.name("id_itemSummaryView")) //throws error
```

OR

```
itemElement.findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation("elements()[0]")); //throws error
```

Appium logs:

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/31a28dd4-f03f-48eb-a21d-31d991bbd90e/element/33/element {"id":"33","using":"name","value":"id_itemSummaryView"}

info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElementByName('id_itemSummaryView', '33')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementByName('id_itemSummaryView', '33')

info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
info: [debug] Condition unmet after 85ms. Timing out.
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":7,"value":{"message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.","origValue":""},"sessionId":"31a28dd4-f03f-48eb-a21d-31d991bbd90e"}
```

Even from Appium Inspector, I set "Search from Selected Element" and try finding the element. Doesn't work.

- Has anyone got finding element inside element working with Appium on iOS app?
- Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a bug in Appium?

Note: I have also raised a [ticket](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5460) on Appium's github repo.